# Spring data rest jpa post object with existing related entity

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have two entities

```
@Entity
public class ForwardRule {

@Column(nullable = false)
private String identifier;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
}

@Entity
public class User {    
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long userId;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String identifier;

}
```

For both I have Repositories annotated with: @RepositoryRestResource

I have an existing user and I want to post a FowardRule with an existing User.

```
String requestJson = "{" +
"\"identifier\": \"6bff6eb0-9b47-42fd-8ac6-339a93aa310d\"," +
"\"user\" : {\"href\":\"http://localhost:9000/users/1\"}"+
"}";
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestJson, headers);
String answer = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:9000/forwardRules", entity, String.class);
System.out.println(answer);
```

As a result I get a mysql exception: Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'user_id' cannot be null

I would like to know two things:

1. why is the user_id null
2. how can I do the post with Java objects? In following style. This works for getting and posting simple objects.

   ForwardRuleView newOne = new ForwardRuleView();
   newOne.setUser(existingUser);
   newOne.setIdentifier("howie");
   ResponseEntity forwardRuleViewResponseEntity = new RestTemplate().postForEntity("http://localhost:9000/forwardRules", newOne, ForwardRuleView.class);

**Update**

Json post can be done with:

```
 String requestJson = "{" +
    "\"identifier\": \"6bff6eb0-9b47-42fd-8ac6-339a93aa310d\"," +
    "\"user\" : {"http://localhost:9000/users/1\"}"+
    "}";
```

Only need to know how I can post it with Pojo's